# Great question got deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

This is a [cross-post from meta.programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1293/2366). I think the discussion also belongs here and to be honest, I’m really angry at the moment and I want this to get some attention.

Executive summary: deleting sucks. Don’t do it. You’re destroying the internet.

---

The deletion mafia has struck again. We had this discussion before on Meta.SO.

Case in point: the question [What do you say to people when they say that programming is not demanding?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37316) was deleted.

Can we just please, *please* agree that this is not constructive behaviour and that questions – even ones that get closed for valid reasons – should **not** be deleted except when they are really disruptive?

The question above ([cached copy here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XVdaauL6aP0J:programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/37316/what-do-you-say-to-people-when-they-say-that-programming-is-not-demanding/37318+https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37316&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com)) wasn’t a great question but it got *great* answes and I had linked to it elsewhere. It is just *really* annoying that such questions get deleted, and it completely runs counter the spirit of the Internet: *do not let links go stale*.

I’m serious about this. **Pervasive deleting destroys these sites. It’s a bad attitude and it needs to stop.**

---

**Proposal**: I propose to actually revoke deletion rights from power users. It’s a completely useless ability. The few deletion that are actually necessary (e.g. for legal reasons) can easily be done by moderators. Granting deletion rights to many users directly leads to abuse. And I’m arguing that almost *every* deletion is abuse.

---

> **Related:**
>   [Should popular questions be so easy to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8282/should-popular-questions-be-so-easy-to-delete)

Comment: That teaches you to link to pages on SE when you know deletions happen

Comment: I agree with you. I voted undelete.

Comment: That one was deleted by a site moderator; I don't know the full context, but asking on the site's meta is the best option. I would offer my *regular* undelete vote, but I can't - it would be binding. I don't want to strong-arm it...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I have noticed a few moderators say something like that, "I would vote to X but my vote would be binding". Maybe moderators should be given the option to cast votes as either binding or non-binding.

Comment: @Brian: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote

Comment: -1 for re-hashing this ancient issue and for posting it in an obviously accusatory and inflammatory tone.  You want to talk *not constructive behaviour*, let's talk about making broad sweeping statements railing against a critical feature because one your favourite questions happened to get singled out as crap.

Comment: Please avoid cross posting. The request to have this question undeleted belongs on meta.programmers, and the request to remove the delete feature belongs on meta.so. Posting the same question on multiple sites is discouraged, however posting off-topic questions (or mixing off topic into on-topic questions) is certainly discouraged.

Comment: I deleted it on 18th February - a month ago now. Unfortunately there's no dialog that comes up to ask you to enter a reason for the deletion so I can't remember *why* I decided that question should be deleted.

Comment: Flushing a toilet is a waste of water. I propose that from now on we ban flushing toilets.

Comment: @ChrisF: If you can't, by looking at the question, immediately tell _why_ it was deleted, deleting it might have been _wrong_.

Comment: @sbi - the question itself is a bad question - which is why it was closed in the first place. The vast majority of answers are one liners - so it's not eliciting well thought out, reasoned responses. Two of the answers are links to xkcd comics - not a good sign. There were a couple of good answers, but on the whole the question didn't add anything to the site.

Comment: @ChrisF: I wasn't criticizing the fact that the question was ___closed___. (FWIW, I haven't even _looked_ at the question.) I was just pointing out that, if you come to a question that you have ___deleted___ after some time, and don't ___immediately___ see why it was ___deleted___, you might have done wrong ___deleting___ it.

Comment: @sbi - I take your point, but I posted that comment after an initial look at the question and didn't come back to clarify - which I should have done.

Comment: @Brian - I am not an elected moderator of that site; I'd rather "house rules" etc...

Comment: @sbi: Please don't conflate the deletion of long-running complaints here on meta by the dev team with the deletion of poor questions on individual Stack Exchanges by their moderators. The two have practically no relationship whatsoever.

Comment: @Aarobot Yes: this *was* an accusation. Thanks for noticing. What’s wrong with that? As for inflammatory, nope, sorry. There’s nothing inflammatory with decrying a fundamentally flawed behaviour.

Comment: @Adam You have given an excellent reason *for* cross-posting: the request for un-deletion belongs on meta, the discussion belongs here. Both are related, hence cross-posting.

Comment: @Konrad Hopefully I have given an excellent reason for not mixing two issues in the same post.  If not, consider that some people may agree with undeleting that question, but they don't agree with removing deletion altogether.  How should they vote?  You are losing upvotes you might receive if you separated your issues.

Comment: @Konrad: *What's wrong with that?*  The fact that you do it in the same breath as lamenting other users' "non-constructive behaviour". Opening a dialogue with guns blazing is the epitome of unconstructive and your apparent obliviousness to all the prior dialogue makes it especially obnoxious. Next time, if you want people to listen to you, choose a *specific* issue instead of mixing them up and cross-posting them like Adam says, and at least *pretend* to entertain the possibility that other people have good reasons for the things they do.

Comment: @Aarobot The non-constructive behaviour was the *gist* of my criticism. If I can’t criticise other people, what kind of place is this?

Comment: @Konrad: this is the sort of place where we expect you to justify your criticisms with informed arguments. "Something happened that I don't much care for - IT'S THE MAFIA! Let's take away users' rights!" isn't doing that. The fact that you were utterly misinformed about what really happened doesn't put you in a good light either.

Comment: reopening cause I would like to deal with this specific case.

Comment: @Shog9 But as others have noted we had this argument before – and the agreement I remember was that entirely too much gets deleted. I admit that I hadn’t anticipated such a huge controversy, else I would have argued my point better to begin with. For me it was straightforward: the question isn’t great but it’s on-topic, it got great answers, generated a lot of interest – such questions should **never** be deleted, links to it shouldn’t go stale.

Comment: @Konrad: Ah, well this makes more sense then. Yes, users are discouraged from deleting willy-nilly... But that's not what happened here (and, I dare say, the attitude toward deleting *duplicates* is a bit different from that toward questions considered off-topic - a concept that has also been refined a bit since that post was written).

Answer (score 29):

Closing is not enough. By the time a reasonable, but off topic question is closed, it has accrued an answer or two, and the person who asked it gets what they wanted, even though they posted a question that isn't allowed on the site.

If we do not delete questions which are inappropriate for this site then people will understand that such questions still result in answers and reputation, and they will ask them more frequently than they already do. This will drop the signal to noise ratios, and the site would lose it's laser sharp focus.  Experts would get fed up with the low signal to noise ratio and leave.

We must aggressively protect our niche, and deleting is one of the very important tools for this.

Further, if we remove deletion we're going to have to fundamentally change how the site operates.  Deletion removes reputation accrued to bad questions, so removing it allows yet another way to game reputation.  Deletion removes the question from google search results, and for bad questions with no answers, people would end up here via google, and see that their question isn't answered here, simply because they used the same terminology as the person who wrote the bad question.  This is bad branding.

Lastly, if a question lasted long enough to get several great answers, it's quite possible that it ended up in the data dump prior to deletion.  You can get that information out of the data dump.  Worst case, you post a message on meta asking that a 10k user give you the content so you can repost it on your site.

The end game for Stack Exchange is that a site will exist for every reasonable question, so ultimately your request will come to pass simply due to the fact that we will have a place to migrate good, but off topic, questions.

Until then, though, it's critically important to maintain a **very high** signal to noise ratio, avoid rep gaming, and make sure we don't pollute search engine indices.

Comment: +1 for this, although "reasonable" in your second-to-last paragraph is a subjective term on its own - if a question was deleted for being not constructive, as opposed to off-topic, then it's probably never going to find a home on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Aarobot Yes, I could change *"reasonable question"* to *"question which meets the given site's FAQ guidelines for what constitutes an acceptable question"* but I'm trying to be a little less verbose in my writing.  Edit away if you have a better phrasing for that point!

Comment: *people will understand that such questions still result in answers and reputation, and they will ask them more frequently than they already do* - Imho simply removing reputation from closed questions will solve this problem in the same way. I'm also not a fan of deleting.

Answer (score 10):

Keep in mind that the question ***was not actually a question.***

> It may not be physically demanding but it sure is mentally demanding.

There are several ways I could close this question.  I could close this question as `not constructive`, or I could close it as `not a real question`.  I could also close it for being `argumentative`; it's not objective, and it's not a good subjective question.

It's clear what the question asker thinks about this subject, which makes it inappropriate.    By stating his/her opinion, we not only encourage a lot of "me too" answers, but he/she also opens the door for some argumentative answers.  This is not what Stack Exchange is about, since there are already several forums on the Internet that encourage this type of traffic.

With that said, this question could have been improved by leaving out the opinion in the question.  However, because of all of the answers, I think it was too late to fix the problem.

If the problem was caught early, even after being improved, it still might be closed, but at least it wouldn't show a blatant disregard for the information in the [Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq).

In my mind, if too many of the rules are broken in a question, then we just don't want it in our community at all.  These types of questions aren't what Stack Exchange is about, and they won't help the site attract and keep professional experts.

Answer (score 7):

The issue in this case (and I don't actually *disagree* with it) is that a diamond mod issued the delete.

Other than that, this has all been discussed before:

[The Great Question Deletion Audit of 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2010)

And there are rules around it, which a diamond moderator is immune to

[Should delete votes be limited like close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes)

I don't think there's much of value in the particular question under discussion, but I will save that response for where it belongs -- meta.programmers.

Comment: I agree with Adam's answer: protect your niche, do what you have to do and remove what you want. But don't *just* delete those popular (but bad) questions. They are not a problem but an *opportunity*: to reiterate my [previous suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74918#comments-74918), *move* them to an "outcast.stackexchange.com" (so previous external references to those questions are still valid, since they would be automatically redirected to "outcast"), strip any reputation gained from those questions (no rep gaming), and explain in their new page why they have been moved (educate).

Comment: @VonC: someone else had that idea... It became Programmers.SE (and changed focus into something approaching useful). I doubt it'll get tried again.

Comment: @vonc there is no reason questions like that need to exist in our network -- programmers is more subjective, but it is not "anything goes" and questions and answers *must* be constructive to be of lasting value

Comment: @VonC: Opportunity for *what*?  You left out what should have been the most important part of your argument. And, incidentally, reputation and "rep gaming" really don't enter into it at all.

Comment: @Aarobot: uh? "educate"? last word of my argument: helping to transform the popularity of those questions, which had an impact and a *lasting* value (for the wrong reasons) for a lot of people into a way to help them: a/ discover there is a lot more behind "favorite cartoon" and make them discover what Stack Exchange is all about b/ understand why "favorite cartoon" type of questions won't be allowed on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @vonc so if there is lots of trash on the street with little "please don't litter" signs placed next to them, people will understand that it is bad for there to be trash on the streets?

Comment: @Jeff: I understand those questions must not exist on a normal Stack Exchange site; that is why I propose for those to a/ keep a winning value for you as essentially a static content for educate and advertise newcomers to the constructing value *actually* proposed by all the other Stack Exchange, while b/ keeping their (frozen) content available to the many casual visitors who knew about their content (while not realizing this wasn't the right kind of answer): win-win. Again: **an opportunity to advertise and educate about what Stack Exchange is really about**. Lasting value to me;)

Comment: @Jeff: essentially yes: no questions of those kind will have ever the opportunity to get that big (in number of views, favorites and votes: which is why it was upsetting to see them "vanish" in the first place), because they would be closed much more rapidly, with a comment pointing to that kind of old, historic question. And if one still falls through the cracks, you have a natural place to move them to, instead of just deleting them, while keeping the content of the original SE site clean.

Comment: @vonc this is irrelevant; there is usually enough time (a day or three) when such things hang around to educate. They do not need to be immortalized in granite for future generations to admire.

Comment: @Jeff: I respect your point of view, I was simply trying to propose a win-win alternative to the "delete the trash" quick-fix (for popular questions only, even when they are deleted by votes), but as I said in other questions: your site. your rules.

Comment: @Jeff “there is no reason questions like that need to exist” – more importantly, there is no reason they *don’t* need to exist. Deletion is a  very one-sided approach and I still fail to see how the advantages of deletion in most cases outweighs the disadvantages. Opinions will always differ, why quell them? This isn’t a filing cabinet about to overflow, this is the internet.

Comment: @VonC: I frankly find that a BS explanation and the same tired old explanation everybody else uses for objectionable content.  "Educational" is every bit as subjective and open to interpretation as "opportunity". I'm not buying it, and referencing the cartoon thread as being "a lot more behind [...]" just undermines the rest of the argument, as there really was *nothing* else to find in there.

Comment: Anyway @VonC, from experience we've all seen that these broken windows certainly do *not* help to educate people on the proper usage of SO/SE, they just encourage copycats. Even if they're closed, there's a large subset of people who won't notice or care. And it's true that there is a subset of simpletons who, if you delete them, will think "oh, I guess I must be the first person with this idea!" but they are vastly outnumbered by those who will recognize the lack of any similar questions as a red flag.

Comment: @Konrad: Honestly I'm sorry if this comes off as rude or elitist but you really need to start by reading the old meta discussions and blog posts and even the original podcasts before coming in here and venting. This issue has been debated a thousand times over and you seem to be coming in here with no context whatsoever. Your 89k Stack Overflow reputation only makes it all the more painful that you don't already know the answers to the questions you're asking.

Comment: @Aarobot: just to be clear, I never proposed to leave those broken windows in their original SE sites: remove them by all means. But since many people did find them useful/entertaining, I was advocating for a special SE site ("outcast"), with an explicit name illustrating how those questions aren't welcome, and with, for each one, an introduction explaining where they came from and why they are in "outcast.se": that would have been the *educating* part, while preserving the original address (which is what Konrad alluded to in his question), since it would redirect to outcast.

Comment: @Aarobot So you’re basically saying: if you don’t participate in meta, your opinion isn’t welcome? Sorry, that doesn’t work. It’s a pity that SO mixes technical discussions (meta) with off-topic (also meta) – as a result, participating in meta is utterly time-consuming, which is why I don’t do it. Were the two distinct, I would undoubtably have known about the discussion beforehand. That said, I read *all* blog posts and have heard all the old podcasts so I’m reasonably well-informed, I believe.

Comment: @Konrad: no, he's saying if you don't *read* meta then you're arguing a position that has been rebutted countless times already, and wasting all of our time by failing to add anything new to the discourse. Start with the posts that've been linked here - folks took the time to dig them up for you, you could at least give them that much...

Comment: @VonC: Fair enough.  It was a reasonable enough suggestion for its time, but it's important for you to be aware of the history here and understand that *what is now Programmers.SE was originally created to be exactly what you describe.* The SE team and many prominent members were unimpressed with the result, which is why the concept of "not constructive" was created and the moderation was tightened up. As of now, the team has categorically stated that there will *never* be an "anything goes" SE or even a static archive hosted on the SO/SE network.

Comment: @VonC bottom line is that a separate ghetto for content deemed inappropriate is like a "maybe pile" at the shopping mall - all you're doing is procrastinating, delaying the inevitable decision you'll have to make. Eventually the "Outcast.SE" will become so polluted as to be virtually unusable, and you'll just have to do the same thing that was already done with Programmers.SE, and if you remember how things panned out with Programmers.SE, it was *not fun* to try to change the scope after the free-for-all was established. Some would say that they are still reeling from the after-effects.

Comment: @Aarobot: PSE isn't exactly what I am proposing. Like not at all. PSE is for open question about programming. SO is about closed question. The "outcast.se" would be for any *popular* questions (for whatever wrong reason) of *any* SE sites which are deemed having no lasting values per SE criteria, but still had some values for the many who voted/favorited/viewed said questions.  Outcast isn't meant to be "usable" (no vote or comment can go there), only to be completed by an intro on each questions explaining why they have not their place on SE. Again: *nothing* to do with PSE.

Comment: @VonC: The network has regular data dumps and all content is cc-wiki.  You or anybody else is welcome to put it up on a static repository if you/they really think it's so valuable. Your proposal is asking the team (and communities) to do extra work to preserve content they don't want - I cannot think of a single rational reason why they should.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree that that’a a problem but from what I gather the discussion is all over the place and cannot simply be read up. I did read all of the links provided here and I didn’t find a definitive discussion of deletion. For the [last discussion about deletion that I actively followed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50069/1968) the result was that yes, much too much gets deleted, let’s discourage it.

Comment: @Jeff: This is somewhat off-topic, but I don't think it's appropriate to post as a new question. I'm curious why you deleted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456205/get-read-only-textboxes-within-disabled-groupbox). I agree it isn't very well written and could probably use an edit. But I don't think it's "noise", and I certainly think it's answerable. I wouldn't have disagreed with a vote to close, but I struggle to understand why it merited a deletion when, for example, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455792/what-is-good-code) (which you only closed) didn't.

Comment: Please note that I don't mean for this to be accusatory or inflammatory towards you (and that's the primary reason I don't think it should be a new question). There's just been confusion recently about what exactly merits deletion, and I'm curious what your standards are.

Answer (score 5):

For context, this is the particular bit of content it seems people are upset about losing:

---

### What do you say to people when they say that programming is not demanding?

Ask them if writing a small 100 page novel in English **without a single spelling or grammatical error** is mentally demanding.

Further explain to them that this novel is actually **someone else's story** that you have to write as they explain it to you.

That person **only speaks Chinese** (luckily you are bilingual), so **you have to translate it** from
Chinese to English as you go.

Then to top it off, the **person isn't exactly sure what the story they want is**, so they can only help you get it right by informing you when you have done it wrong from their vague descriptions.

You have to **complete this in 3 days**.

(In rare DailyWTF stories: *Your boss insists on helping, despite being semi-illiterate*)

**Now is it demanding?**

Written by: Dan McGrath

---

Is this interesting content?

**Yes**

Does this content make the Internet a better place?

**Possibly**

Does this content belong on programmers.se?

**That totally depends on the community running the site**

---

Should we make engine level changes that make it impossible to remove content from a site?

**No, I don't think so**

---

The community and moderators should have the right to decide what content they think belongs on the site, for example:

What if the most **awesome** answer **ever** is posted on SO, it gets 100s of votes, but turns out to be off-topic. An example could be a question regarding employment law, with an answer by a prominent lawyer in the field. Great content, however, off topic.

Leaving content like that on SO, sets a bad example and sends a totally wrong message to people visiting the site. We have no place in the network for such content at the moment so we are stuck with the unfortunate task of deleting it.

I think the best way to solve this **orphan great content** issue, is to simply provide it in the data dump, perhaps include all deleted posts with more than X votes with in a "we have no home for this content" dump. Then others that feel like the content needs a new home can host a web site where it can thrive. As it stands 10k users on the respective sites can grab the content and host it elsewhere if they feel so strongly about it, provided the licensing terms are filled.

Comment: You seem to have the wrong question quoted. There's nothing "great" about it. Unless we're into typos of "grate."

Comment: ahhh @random ... will I be seeing you in the SO meetup next month?

Comment: If it was last year, yes. But you'll have to see the IP of last user activity to see why this year is kind of out.

Comment: @random, that is why we need scram jets

Answer (score 4):

I think deletion powers are a tricky problem. On the one hand, I agree with you. It's incredibly frustrating when good questions (or more commonly, poor questions with exceptional answers) get deleted. It many cases it only takes a small cabal of power users with a bone to pick, and voila - mass deletion of borderline or even good content. It's hard to notice, because only a small number of users can even see such actions. And even when it's noticed, [it's incredibly tough, antagonistic and unrewarding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54215/why-is-python-so-slow-shouldnt-have-been-closed-and-deleted) to get them back. Once a question has been deleted, it becomes a case of "guilty, until proven innocent".

On the other hand, sites like Stack Overflow get *a lot* of [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362072/c-programming-concepts) [terrible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359161/monte-carlo-algorithm) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351111/design-pattern-practices) (those are just a few at random from the last few hours). They are closed quickly, but after that, they just sit around uselessly. They're not valuable, they are indexed by Google, and they are noise. No one ever needs to see them. They will waste the time of anyone who visits their page. They reduce the quality level of the site and make it harder to find the good stuff.

It would be nice to be able to leverage the community to clean them up.

In your specific case, the problem was heavy-handed moderation from a true ♦ moderator, which is always going to be a difficult case. Moderators need the power and authority to make big decisions, but oversight of their actions is important, and they have a special responsibility to be sensitive to their power (see Marc Gravell's comment above). I think bringing the issue to meta, on a case by case basis is the correct thing to do here.

There have been steps taken to address problematic deletions (see the other comments and answers) by users, which I think cover most of my former objections, so I withdraw my other proposals.

Comment: in general see my answer. #4 already happens, we auto-delete migration stubs after a while.

Comment: Also, as Jeff points out, #1 is somewhat addressed by the fact that the upvotes on a question increase the number of delete votes required to remove it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071 .

Comment: I agree with everything you say, up until the list of changes at the end.

Comment: @Mark Rogers, Jeff Atwood, Brad Larson: All good points. I had forgotten about the modifications to the deletion criteria, which largely cover what I was aiming for. I withdraw my proposals.