# May we please have the SO "Easter Egg" question back?

Tags: support, undelete

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9177#9177) in the recently-necromanced "Jon Skeet Facts" thread:

> Jon Skeet once fixed a production problem in his pajamas.

That page links to a citation - what used to be a picture of Jon Skeet in his pajamas. This was the page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140376/what-easter-eggs-have-you-placed-in-code#140507

However, that page seems to be gone, which is a net loss for SO because it is referenced by other pages. There are over a thousand pages on the internet which reference that link, including the aforementioned "Jon Skeet Facts" page. Which is now gone.

May we please have this page back? Maybe transfer it to meta?

I mean, that thread has been around since the very beginning, and I was basically here in the very beginning, so I feel like a part of my upbringing has died.

How about this: since I have been a long-time SO contributor, may I please have the ability to view questions deleted by arm chair moderators? Or can you set it up so that if the referer is "google" then the page magically un-deletes so that we don't break google's search results? I hate it when google 404s.

Comment: Even if we reinstate this one, it's probably not going to come to meta as it has nothing to do with our site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should we do with old, very popular closed questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33786/what-should-we-do-with-old-very-popular-closed-questions), [Great question got deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83825/), [What should we do with old, very popular closed questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33786/), [Building an archive of deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/), [Set up an archive for legendary deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73226/), etc. *ad nauseum*

Comment: Hmm, right as I was posting my answer, I noticed a new blog post: [Stack Exchange’s Greatest Hits](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/). I mean, using anonymous feedback for something useful is really great, but given the recent rash of complaints about this, I was definitely expecting to see that Jeff had finally created a place for these old, popular questions to go to die (or "wallow in fame" as the case may be) while keeping them off the regular pages of the site.

Comment: You could always use [stackprinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=140376&service=stackoverflow)

Comment: I'll have you know that some of my moderating is done from an armless chair. BUSTED

Comment: I don't get it. This is the internet. If information (or jokes, or anything) is available on Day x, and I check back on Day y | y > x, then I expect the content to be there! Otherwise, please update every single page on the internet (or at least on SO!) which links to that resource so that we don't have a collection of spaghetti 404'd links! Remember geocities when the web basically consisted of 404 errors? How about we, uh, not go back there?

Comment: @mmyers I would believe you but if you posted a pic as proof then your response would be deleted as off-topic.

Answer (score 14):

> How about this: since I have been a long-time SO contributor, may I please have the ability to view questions deleted by arm chair moderators?

We already offer that deal. The condition is that you earn a reputation score of 10,000 or more, then you can see all deleted questions and answers.

Apparently you haven't been a contributor for quite long enough.

Comment: I mean, your SO reputation is a function of how good your answers are and the amount of time you spend using the site. Possibly I have neither, but let's say that I don't have 10k rep because I have not spent enough hours answering questions. It is unfair that something I could read when I was a n00b is now behind a 10k rep paywall.

Comment: @user: Would it be more fair if it weren't available to anyone at all? I'm sure the crowd that enjoys deleting these questions would be willing to consider accommodating such a request.

Answer (score 12):

Erm, let's not.

Let's apply the Jeff Atwood ["We hate fun here"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) test to the [Easter egg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140376) question, shall we?

1. Does this question match the criteria provided in the Stack Overflow FAQ?  **No.**
2. Is this question accepted by the community, as reflected in upvotes, views, favorites, and answers?
   **Yes.**
3. Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?
   **Highly unlikely.**

1 out of 3.  Sorry, but it doesn't quite make the grade.

Comment: I might disagree with number 3, but of course I am unable to see the original thread in order to cite specific examples of mistakes that people have posted and how they would be more broadly relevant as things not to do. (Eg, numerous stories about easter eggs being found directly translate to cautionary tales about hidden "dev-only" features or test data.)

Comment: Also, I realize that it is not SO's responsibility to accommodate the googlebot, but, well, SO already accommodates the googlebot, so how can that accomodation extend to not causing google links to 404?

Answer (score 5):

I agree that this stuff should be publicly visible somewhere, and being a veteran SO user shouldn't be a requirement to see it - however, it should not be on Stack Overflow proper, as this stuff is clearly off-topic there, nor on Meta, for the same reason. A separate archive might come up in the future: see the comments in [Building an archive of deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/building-an-archive-of-deleted-questions)

At the moment, the only people able to see the question is 10k+ rep users.

Here is [the full account of the pyjama incident](http://piratepad.net/aWK1aLmzOJ), and [a link to the picture](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/pics/pyjamas.jpg). Jon is hosting that image himself so I'm sure he doesn't mind.

Answer (score 4):

You can view it on the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20080929030329/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140376/what-easter-eggs-have-you-placed-in-code).

Answer (score 3):

Many other questions have been locked and closed, rather than delete with the reason given that they provide historical significance and that any similar questions asked nowadays will be deleted:

[image]

I think this situtation fits that category.

We could at least have archive.stackoverflow.com or historical.stackoverflow.com as a place for these questions to go. It would be a more functional mini-site than the current facebook.stackoverflow.com which offers to no additional funcitonality.

Comment: [Uh huh](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nFVEh.jpg)

Comment: @phwd, you seem to be implying my answer makes no sense, I can't quite tell though because your comment was, frankly, useless.

Comment: Using the historical notice feature to keep a pointless useless question is wrong. The value to be gained from the easter eggs question is close to nil. An archive of informative useful content for programmers is good everything else needs to die silently. Find a question that even drops to the level of Easter eggs, is closed and locked but not deleted and I will agree with you. Gathering these questions, that are trivial nature only adds to the distraction plate of a contributor on this site rather than you know, answering real questions and producing real content.

Comment: @phwd, erm the Jon Skeet thread at linked at the top, objectively is equally irrelevant to MSO as the Easter Egg is to SO, and it has been locked for historical reasons. The historical lock is for questions that are off topic but have a high amount of votes and are old to enough to exist. There is nothing more frustrating on the internet than finding a page that doesnt exist. Also locked and old questions do not clutter the site as they stay hidden at page 100+, and are found through links like the OP has. What causes distraction is these question *being* asked, not *been* asked.